# Download transitive dependencies with Gradle

Tags: dependencies, gradle

My Gradle project depends on a Jar artifact.
I'd like to download dependent Jar together with its own dependencies (transitive for the main project) into a temporary build folder:

```
configurations {
    myConfig { transitive = true }
}

dependencies {
    myConfig "my-group:my-artifact:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
}

task copyMyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.myConfig
    into temporaryDir
}
```

Unfortunately, I get only my-artifact.jar file in the build/tmp/copyMyLibs folder.
I'd like to see there dependencies of the "my-group:my-artifact:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" too.

What would be the most succinct way of expressing that in Gradle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be the most succinct way of expressing that in Gradle?

You are already expressing it (`transitive = true` is the default). Chances are that the dependency doesn't have a descriptor (pom.xml or ivy.xml), or doesn't have any transitive dependencies. Also note that snapshots are cached for 24 hours by default (`--refresh-dependencies` is one way to overcome that).

Comment: Thanks, @Peter! I think you're exactly right and the reason is the absent module descriptor (pom.xml) for my dependency. I'll try to generate it and check whether that helps me.

Comment: Yep, missing pom.xml was the reason.